# React Intl's FormatedMessage not taking id as a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

This way it's working

```
  <FormattedMessage id={'idName'}/>
```

This way it's not ><

```
<FormattedMessage id={idVariable}/>
```

Throwing this error :

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: [React Intl] An `id` must be provided to
> format a message.

When I console.log(idVariable) it gaves me the correct id I don't get it.

Any help ?

Comment: Where did you put the variable? is it within the parent component?

Comment: @DavidSalomon Yes I store it it another file, getting it by static function and then passing to the children with props. Then using props.idVar and as I said it is good when I console.log but white page when I pass it directly as a variable in the <FormatedMessage>

Comment: Paste the full code to see how you implemented it

Comment: I can't share it ... Is it another way to explain or show my problem ?